# InStr doesn't appear to be working in this validation sub. Does anyone have any idea why?

Tags: arrays, string, vba, excel, comparison

I am checking two different directories that the user enters to make sure they don't contain any of the symbols that windows doesn't allow for folder names. The two directories are strings named outputFolder and dirName, and the forbidden characters are stored in an array named msWinFolderChars. I have a for loop checking the two directories for each character one at a time and (ideally) alerting the user and killing the sub if one is found. What actually happens though is that if I enter an invalid character the program doesn't find it and runs through until it actually opens that directory, at which point it crashes because it won't find a folder with an invalid character. Does anyone see where this went wrong?

```
For Each char In msWinFolderChars
If InStr(outputFolder, char) = Not 0 Then
    MsgBox ("You have entered an invalid output folder name. Please try again without using " & char)
    Exit Sub
ElseIf InStr(dirName, char) = Not 0 Then
    MsgBox ("You have entered an invalid CSV directory. Please try again without using " & char)
    Exit Sub
End If
Next
```

Comment: `Not 0` equals -1. You should use `<> 0` instead.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Use `If InStr(outputFolder, char) <> 0 Then` instead

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Rory explained above that `not 0` equals -1, which caused the calculations to be wrong.